# How can I monitor the events that cause the frequency of Intel CPU and Graphis to reduce, such as "Package/Platform-Level Power Limiting PL1 Status"

Tags: python, gpu, cpu, intel, msr

I am not very familiar with Intel's architectures but I need to access the events that trigger Intel CPU and Graphis limited performace for my project (particularly reduced frequency).

I tried to find something related in Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual and I found that some MSRs (not exactly sure what these are) may just provide what I need (see images below).

[image]
[image]

How can I access these information using Python?